# Retrieve Specific Data from SQL database using PHP

Tags: php, sql

so for a project, I have to add data into a SQL database and then based on the users choice different data will be displayed.

**This is exactly my professor's directions**
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/987rb.png)

I have added the data to my SQL database but I'm currently struggling with how to retrieve them.

**This is how I have the website set up** [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJqS5.png)

**This is where the users will add their input**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <?php
      include_once 'includes/dbc.php';
     ?>
     <br>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Final - Shoe Store</title>
    <style media="screen">
      footer{
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #4d4d4d;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 50%;
      }
      .header{
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #4d4d4d;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
      }
      body {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        margin: 15%;
        text-align: center;
        zoom: 150%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <div class="header">
    <h1> Final - Shoe Store </h1>
  </div>
  <body>
<p>Please complete this form to see the prices.</p>
<p> <span style="color:#FF0000;" >* required field</span> </p>

<form action="handler.php" method="post">
  <p>
    <label> What brand of shoes would you like?
      <select name="brand" required>
        <option value="NULL" selected disabled>---------</option>
        <option value="adidas">Adidas</option>
        <option value="converse">Converse</option>
        <option value="nike">Nike</option>
        <option value="reebok">Reebok</option>
      </select>
    </label>
      <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>What type of shoes do you want?
      <select name="type" required>
        <option value="NULL" selected disabled>-----------------</option>
        <option value="basketball">Basketball Shoes</option>
        <option value="fitness">Fitness Shoes</option>
        <option value="running">Running Shoes</option>
        <option value="walking">Walking Shoes</option>
      </select>
    </label>
      <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>How many shoes would you like?
      <input type="text" name="quantity" required>
    </label>
      <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Choose `Adult` or `Children` to get the price for the shoes.</label>
  </p>
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
    <input type="submit" name="adult" value="Adult">
    <input type="submit" name="children" value="Children">
</form>
  </body>
  <footer>© 2018 Guillermo Molina Matus. All Rights Reserved.</footer>
</html>
```

**and this is the handler.php which is the file that handles the input**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>

     <br>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Fianl - Lumber</title>
    <style media="screen">
      footer{
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #4d4d4d;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 50%;
      }
      .header{
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #4d4d4d;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
      }
      body {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        margin: 15%;
        text-align: center;
        zoom: 150%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <div class="header">
    <h1> Final - Shoe Store </h1>
  </div>
  <body style="background-color: lightgrey">
    <?php
    //Renaming the values
    $adult = isset($_POST['adult']);
    $children = isset($_POST['children']);
    $type = isset($_POST['type']);
    $quantity = isset($_POST['quantity']);
    $brand = isset($_POST['brand']);
    $delete = isset($_POST['delete']);


      //If they click on the inches button
      if ($adult)
      {
        include_once 'includes/dbc.php';
        if (($brand == "adidas")){
        echo "Adult<br>";} else {
          echo "no";
        }

    //display your result
  echo "The total price would be $";
      }
      elseif ($children) {
        include_once 'includes/dbc.php';
        echo "Children<br>";

    //display your result
  echo "The total price would be $";
      }
      elseif ($delete) {

        include_once 'includes/dbc_delete.php';
      }


     ?>
     <br>
     <br>
     <form action="input.php" method="post">
       <input type="submit" name="home" value="Go Home">
     </form>
  </body>
  <footer>
    © 2018 Guillermo Molina Matus. All Rights Reserved.
  </footer>
</html>
```

The main problem that I'm having is showing the customer the proper price according to their selections. I would just like to know how to retrieve the correct price according to their selection.

 
 [This is how my database is setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2bSU.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
select sum('price') from products GROUP BY brands,kindOfShoes.
```

Just giving you insights. You can do something like this. Above will give you the total price of each brands and kindofshoes. Try this and see this will help if not comment.

Answer (score -1):

My first recommendation would be to normalize your database.

In your current scenario, you can easily fetch data by multiple AND condition in your a query.

For instance, in raw PHP you can use data from $type, $brand etc to fill up values in below-mentioned query dynamically.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM YOURDBNAME where Brand='Nike' AND KindOfShoes='Running' AND Age='Adult'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Brand: " . $row["Brand"]. " - KindOfShoes: " . $row["KindOfShoes"]. " " . $row["Age"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: It may help to describe to the OP what you mean by "normlise"

Comment: @MohammadAli the OP doesn't have enough rep to downvote.